# K-nearest-neighbour density estimation using the same data set, k=5

Tags: nearest-neighbor

it is about a non-parameteric density estimation.

So, we have 2  different data 220 values of "good data" and 30  values of  "broke data"
we should use k-nearest-neighbour density estimation for estimate  p(x |c="good data")

In case k=5 we have  p(x |c=good) =(5/220)*(1/V).

If I have right understood, by  k-nearest-neighbour  we should determine V and then get 
p(x |c=good)
If we must find out V for 5 points, then we can solve p(x|c=good)

I have a problem, how to plot und calcucale this probability.
There is picture from book  http://content.foto.mail.ru/mail/zurix/_mypagephoto/h-67.jpg
 What does blue curve mean on graphic of  K  nearest-neighbor density estimation(you can see attach)? Can this curve show boundaries of different V? If yes, where exactly boundary between is classes, each class consists of 5 points???

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: moderators, I think this is a good candidate to be moved to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

it's difficult to guess what the two curves mean without any additional information such as the figure caption or the book title.

My best guess is that the green curve is the true (one dimensional) density from which a sample of data points was drawn. The blue curves seem to be the resulting density estimation function for three different values of k .

This should illustrate the importance of choosing k properly, for k = 1, this overfits the data (high variance of the resulting density estimation function), for k = 30, this 'oversmoothes' the data (high bias of the resulting density estimation function) as it does not reproduce the bump around 0.3 .

In fact, looking at the k=1 example, it looks to me like this is *not* using a pure 1 / V but rather some weighting function. For a pure 1/V estimate per point, I would expect a piecewise constant function (only pieces of horizontal lines).